# Divergence Theorem to compute volume bounded by paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral $$\int_V \nabla \cdot \underline{r}\,dV$$ where $V$ is bounded by the surface $S_c$($S_c$ = part of the surface $z = a^2 - x^2 - y^2$ for which $z \geq 0$) and the plane $z=0$.

Attempt: I have done it via surface integral and obtained the correct answer but when I do it by computing the above, I get something different.

$\nabla \cdot r = 3$ (special case when we take the divergence of a position vector) so we just compute $$3 \int_V dV = 3 \int_0^a \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} r^2 \sin \theta d\theta d\phi dr.$$  Evaluating does not give the required $3 \pi a^4/2$ obtained in the surface integral calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cylindrical coordinates, as the surface has cylindrical symmetry.  The integral you want is

$$3 \int_0^{a^2} dz \: \int_0^{a^2-z} dr \,r \: \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta $$

Note that the volume element in cylindrical coordinates is $r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$, and the bounds are explicitly set by the equation of the paraboloid.  The $3$ comes from your divergence.  You should be able to do out this integral.

My answer for this integral is $3 \pi a^4/2 $.

Comment: Do I have to do the integral in cylindrical coords? The rest of the question (i.e the part where I had to do the surface integral I did  via spherical coords as outlined in the question).  That said, I see my integral that I set up does not distinguish between a hemisphere and a paraboloid.

Comment: Should they not be the same?  The $3\pi a^4/2$ was a show that... so that is how I know I did that part correct.

Comment: Why do you have to do it in spherical coordinates for a surface with cylindrical symmetry?  To assign such a problem that way is not a good way to teach spherical coordinates as nobody in their right mind would compute a volume over such a region that way.  A paraboloid as you define here has an axis of symmetry.

Comment: This is the volume I get for this region.  I do not know how you got your other result.  I would make sure you posed the problem properly.

Comment: The parametrisation we were given in the question was $r = asin \theta cos \phi e_1 + a \sin \theta \sin \phi e_2 + a^2 \cos^2 \theta e_3$

Comment: Yes, it is all posed correctly.

Comment: That certainly implies that $x^2+y^2+z=a^2$ as you specified.  I hope you see the axis of symmetry here.

Comment: The paraboloid is symmetrical with respect to the z axis. But my parametrisation uses $\theta, \phi$ so this means the use of spherical polars.

Comment: Look, examine what I have done.  if you find a fault with it, point it out.  But I am satisfied with the result.

Comment: I am not at all suggesting you are wrong, I just want to understand why the results are different. In spherical polars, I obtained the result given in the question.  Could there be a fault with the question?  Thanks.

Comment: I definitely see your point and it is clear that the axis of symmetry suggests cylindrical polars. Any ideas why the results be different?

Comment: I'd have to see your work.

Comment: Is it okay to post it in the comments?

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: I obtained $$r \cdot dS = a^4( 2 \sin^3 \theta \cos \theta + \cos^3 \theta \sin \theta) d \theta d \phi.$$  (This is part of another show that..).  Then I integrated the below: $$a^4 \int_o^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} 2 \sin^3 \theta \cos \theta + \cos^3 \theta \sin  \theta\,d\theta d\phi$$ and got my result.

Comment: I have to go, but I'll have a look later.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  When I do your integral though, I do get the answer on my sheet.

Comment: I did too, another mistake on my part.  OK, are we cool?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  But in terms of doing $$\int_V \nabla \cdot r\,dV$$ via spherical (I reliase now cylindrical is the best way, but in keeping with the rest of the sheet), what is wrong with my integral I wrote in the question?

Comment: The integration limits describe a hemisphere, not a paraboloid.

Comment: What would change for a paraboloid?(z would change but that is not a variable in spherical polars)

Comment: $r$ is not a constant at the surface, but depends on $\theta$.

Comment: The projection of the surface onto the xy plane is a circle of radius a, which is the same as the projection of a hemisphere onto the xy plane. So how would this change r?